# AJAX linked cgi python script completing, but still returning error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cgi

I have a CGI python script that sends an email to the account specified in an AJAX request (taken from a form).

```
def getEmail():
    parameter = cgi.FieldStorage()
    a = parameter.getvalue('email')
    sent_from = gmail_user  
    SUBJECT = "Thanks"
    TEXT = "Hey"
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT) 
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, a, message)
    server.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getEmail()
```

Received from:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$('#regbut').click(function(){
    alert('Im going to start processing');
    $.ajax({
            url: "/cgi-bin/register.py",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#frm").serialize(),                   
            success: function(data){                
                alert("Well done boyo");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }           
    });
});
});
</script>
```

This script actually works. It sends the email to the entered location. However, the AJAX never accepts it as succeeding - the alert never goes off. Infact, I entered an alert into the error area, and that activated instead. Console.log(response) produces this error:

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/y.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/y.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/y.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/y.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/y.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/y.abort(), state: .Deferred/e.state(), always: .Deferred/e.always(), catch: .Deferred/e.catch(), 8 more… }
```

But I couldn't find out what this means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(This is all running on an apache server through localhost, if that matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was to do with setting async. Not setting async means that the program immediately goes to error - I presume because it hasn't waited for the script to finish executing. So adding `async: false` fixes the issue:

```
$(function()
{
$('#regbut').click(function(){
    alert('Im going to start processing');
    $.ajax({
            url: "/cgi-bin/register.py",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#frm").serialize(),
            async: false,               
            success: function(data){                
                alert("Well done boyo");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }           
    });
});
});
```

However, this causes another issue, in that async:false is deprecated, but for now, I cannot see another way of fixing this.